# Phonegap cordova android 'project already exists' or runtime error

Tags: android, cordova, path

I post here because this is driving me crazy.

I'm trying to get phonegap to work so:
I installed ADT bundle (eclipse+adt plugin + android SDK) -> by the way their really should update that phonegap getting started tutorial which is still telling you to install all of that separately but instead of android SDK it gives you a link to the ADT bundle...

Anyway
I have set my environment variables, so i can type java, javac, android, ant or whatever everything is fine.

Now when i go to my cordova-android/bin folder with cmd (i'm on windows) and type 'create "d:/dev/android/phonegaptest" "phonegaptest" "phonegaptest"' it tells me 'project already exists'. While the target folder is just an empty folder.

if instead I type 'create "d:/dev/android/any folder name which doesnt exist yet" "phonegaptest" "phonegaptest"' it tells me 'cordova-android\bin\create.js 181,5 MS JScript runtime error path not found'

How can I get this to work ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok I got it

Apparently **you HAVE TO put com.something for package name** or the JS error will come. This may seem obvious for java developers but PhoneGap is used by a lot of web devs who doesn't know anything about packages. So it SHOULD be specified, thanks again to this poorly written doc.
The error doesn't tell you anything about package name problem so it doesn't help either.

Another thing: **if the folder already exist it will tell you 'project already exist'** so just don't create the folder manually.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 11):

I was having same issue. Make sure that the folder in the  do NOT exists already.

D:\phonegap-2.3.0\lib\android\bin>create D:\myprojects\ com.thinkcode Fone2
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Project already exists!

D:\phonegap-2.3.0\lib\android\bin>create D:\myprojects\Fone com.thinkcode Fone2
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Creating new android project...
Copying template files...
Copying js, jar & config.xml files...
Copying cordova command tools...
Updating AndroidManifest.xml and Main Activity...

D:\phonegap-2.3.0\lib\android\bin>

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that the project path doesn't contain spaces

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me. Replace any folders that contain spaces with their 8.3 shorthand, e.g. Progra~1 instead of "Program Files".

Comment: and no dashes also. project path with dash didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Can't upvote yet, but for me it was an issue with a space in the project path!

Answer (score 0):

In command promt: locate to phonegap folder

```
E:\phonegap.2.3.0\lib\android\bin>create E:\<name>hrms com.hrms hrms <enter>
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Creating new android project...
Copying template files...
Copying js, jar & config.xml files...
Copying cordova command tools...
Updating AndroidManifest.xml and Main Activity...

created successfully
```

If project already exist means change project name or package or project location `<folder directory>`.

```
cd E:\hrms
cmd3>E:\hrms>dir

Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Creating new android project...
Copying template files...
Copying js, jar & config.xml files...
Copying cordova command tools...
Updating AndroidManifest.xml and Main Activity...
```