# Microsoft JScript runtime error: path not found

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to create a phonegap project.
While creating the project, I get an error that says:
"create.js(31, 5) Microsoft JScript runtime error: Path not found"

Could someone help me correcting this error??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586931/phonegap-cordova-android-project-already-exists-or-runtime-error

Answer (score 1):

What version of PhoneGap? I think there was a bug that was fixed in versions 2.2 or around there. If you download 2.8 or 3.0 that issue should be fixed.

To go further, check that the folders you are trying to create are set up correct. The documentation around this is pretty weak and the CLI tools are very unforgiving, but I find that certain folders must be there and certain folders must not be there. For me, I hit just about every issue. The project name is used as a class name and a folder name so make sure you choose something that will be a valid class name. The last path of the project path must not exist, but any intermediate paths must exist. In this cmd, everything up to TestProj must exist but trunk must not exist.

bin> create C:\Projects\Cordova\TestProj\trunk com.company.testproj TestProj

If you encounter any of these it won't tell you, it just fails. Hope this helps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586931/phonegap-cordova-android-project-already-exists-or-runtime-error